# Установка 2 приложений из 1 apk

Tags: android, java

Возможно ли установить 2 приложения через 1 apk файл. 
Если да можно какую нибудь более подробную информацию

Comment: насколько я знаю - нет, но одно приложение может иметь два и более иконок в списке приложений. Может это подойдет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Развёрнутый ответ на Ваш вопрос
[One .apk file that installs two apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682576/one-apk-file-that-installs-two-apps)